# Using one or two databases for small ammounts of data

Tags: php, mysql

Is there any pro or con to have either for a website with few ammounts of user data stored? As of now, I have one database with all needed user data (addresses, telephone etc). Now I'm considering making a database to keep track of current events, of which some are linked to specific users. Other than perhaps making it more "tasteful" to separate data by "type" (a user database, and an "event database"), is there any real reason to do so? The amount of users will never go past 100.

Comment: When you say "database", do you by any chance mean "table"?

Comment: No I mean database. Right now the user database is of RDBM containing user data. I'm standing between designing a new database or adding more tables to the current one to handle various events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you actually mean having multiple databases for a small website, then no. You would want 1 database for the entire website, especially if it is small. You would want multiple tables though.

I am assuming you are getting a database and a table mixed up, which would then make your question make sense, and then yes, you would want multiple tables in your database to store different information.

Comment: Ok, I was abit unclear here. I'm not an entire novice an database design. I've already desined a user database using RDBM. Right now I'm standing between adding more tables for events, or designing a second database for events.

Answer (score 5):

If you're going to be linking user data and current event data, it will be significantly easier to have that data in separate tables in a single database.

Answer (score 1):

It's always best to split things. Use one table for users, and another for the events. With a few users you won't have a problem if you use only one. But have it in mind for future references